# Maphilight plugin not working in Wordpress due to jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using the maphilight plugin on a US map so that when the mouse rolls over, the states change colors.

(http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight

with demo:

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html)

I had the following in my header.php (I am using wordpress):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/adventure-journal-child/js/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/adventure-journal-child/js/jquery.metadata.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/adventure-journal-child/js/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
```

It was working great until I installed Styles with Shortcodes (SWS), http://plugins.righthere.com/styles-with-shortcodes/,  to be able to add tabs and tooltips which uses JQuery as well.

The two were causing conflict. So once the jQuery code associated with maphilights was removed my tabs and tooltips work. I have been reading about this and realize loading the code into the header is not ideal anyways. 
My question is: How can I get maphilight to work without causing conflict?

I tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.map').maphilight({fade: false}); /*set true for fading hover effect*/
           });
</script>
```

Can the maphilight plugin use the same jQuery as my Styles with Shortcodes? Is so how do I do this?

I think I need to use wp_enqueue_script in the functions.php, but am not sure how to go about doing it.

My end goal is to be able to roll over a state on the map and it highlights and a tooltip pops up with text and links inside.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to troubleshoot this one since those are paid plugins and we can't see the conflict in your link, but one thing you might try is update your jquery, You are currently on 1.4.2 but they are on 1.5.2

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try that. I put the line: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/adventure-journal-child/js/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
back in and my highlights turned back on and now my tabs are disabled. Here is the page I am playing with: http://militarywom.com/find-an-installation/

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using the [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function instead. I ran into similar issues on a couple WordPress sites until I learned about that function.